# Strut Angle Vs Overhang

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have a 10mm metal disk that is 1mm thick.  It is easily bent when a force is applied (green arrow) to the unsupported edge.

[image: Base Shape]

I need to add a strut, but at what angle?  The part is weight-sensitive, so to keep it simple the strut will be a 1mm wire (single cast part).  A strut with a shallow angle looks like it will buckle, but increasing the angle adds to the overhang.  How do you find the balancing point that gives the most strength?

[image: Strut Angles]

I

Comment: I'm not even close to remembering the equations, but what you would need to do is create an equation where the moment on the disk is based on how far from the edge the support is, but the compression of the support is that force divided by the sine of the angle.  That said, the affect on the disk can't be done as a 2-D model, which is all I ever did in undergrad anyway.

Comment: I found a beam calculator and saw that this a pretty complicated example.  Both the length of the cantilever and angle of the support have a force multiplier.  I went with 40 deg, but I'm still really curious and would love to see the solution to this, even if it was simplified to a 2D beam.